Device tree overlay warnings suggest me to re-define properties from main DTS
I'm creating a device overlay that contains interrupts and reg properties in "overlayed" csi device node that is missing from main device tree. This is (simplified of course) fragment of DTS for my board:
/ {
    interrupt-parent = <&gic>;
    #address-cells = <1>;
    #size-cells = <1>;
    
    //...
    
    soc {
        compatible = "simple-bus";
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <1>;
        ranges;
        
        //...
        
        gic: interrupt-controller@1c81000 {
            //...
        };
    };
};

And this is "overlayed" device's fragment from my device tree overlay:
fragment@1 {
    target = <&soc>;
    __overlay__ {
        /* Do I need this? */ // #address-cells = <1>;
        /* And this? */ // #size-cells = <1>;

        csi: camera-csi@1cb0000 {
            compatible = "allwinner,sun6i-a31-csi";
            reg = <0x01cb0000 0x1000>;
            interrupts = <GIC_SPI 84 IRQ_TYPE_LEVEL_HIGH>;
            clocks = <&ccu CLK_BUS_CSI>,
                <&ccu CLK_CSI_SCLK>,
                <&ccu CLK_DRAM_CSI>;
            clock-names = "bus", "mod", "ram";
            resets = <&ccu RST_BUS_CSI>;
            
            //...
        };
    };
};

During compilation I get following warnings:
camera_overlay.dtso:37.17-43: Warning (reg_format): /fragment@1/__overlay__/camera-csi@1cb0000:reg: property has invalid length (8 bytes) (#address-cells == 2, #size-cells == 1)
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (pci_device_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (pci_device_bus_num): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (simple_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (i2c_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (spi_bus_reg): Failed prerequisite 'reg_format'
camera_overlay.dtso:35.37-65.15: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__/camera-csi@1cb0000: Relying on default #address-cells value
camera_overlay.dtso:35.37-65.15: Warning (avoid_default_addr_size): /fragment@1/__overlay__/camera-csi@1cb0000: Relying on default #size-cells value
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (avoid_unnecessary_addr_size): Failed prerequisite 'avoid_default_addr_size'
camera_overlay.dtbo: Warning (unique_unit_address): Failed prerequisite 'avoid_default_addr_size'
camera_overlay.dtso:35.37-65.15: Warning (interrupts_property): /fragment@1/__overlay__/camera-csi@1cb0000: Missing interrupt-parent

First warnings, as I understand, come from the lack of #address-cells and #size-cells in parent node of node containing reg property. I can easily fix them by adding them to &soc node, but they are already present in main DTS. I also obviously do not define interrupt-parent in my overlay, but it seems it is also defined in main device tree source for the board I am using. Can I safely ignore these warnings, or do I need to re-define properties dtc warns me about the way they are defined in main device tree source? It seems pointless to me, because I would then need to create fragment for / just to re-specify interrupt-parent property, and add two "dummy" properties to &soc node just to satisfy the compiler. On the other hand I am not sure how my overlay would behave in this situation, for example if the interrupts in "overlayed" device would properly use interrupt-parent in runtime.

The compiler for the overlay cannot see the main DTS.

Yeah that's obvious to me, but my point was more like: will compiled DTO blob still work even if I don't fix these warnings, or it indeed does need to repeat these properties from main DTS to behave correctly when loaded?

It would probably still work, but best to fix the warnings by copying over various meta-properties from the main DTS such as #address-cells, #size-cells, etc. where needed. You may also need to copy over other properties such as ranges.
